# Where can i find some Good backbone-relational tutorials?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-relational

I'm learning backbone.js and the whole microcosmus around it now! But i'm still stunning on one Plugin : The Backbone-Relational.

On [github](https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational) the Documentation is really too short, not for beginner! that's how i feel it!

Do someone have a Tutorial about backbone-relational? i searched google but i really not found something going in that direction.

Thank you a lot for helping me!

Answer (score 11):

I couldn't find any either, so I have written one: [Backbone-relational Tutorial - Nested Models With Backbone.js](http://antoviaque.org/docs/tutorials/backbone-relational-tutorial/)

The answer to the following question can also be worth having a look at - it shows how to structure a sample Todo application with Backbone-relational: [Creating nested models in Backbone with Backbone-relational](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7227597/creating-nested-models-in-backbone-with-backbone-relational)

Comment: Thanks! If you do the video tutorial that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

Some people are busy creating tutorials for Backbone-relational: see https://github.com/PaulUithol/Backbone-relational/issues/77 . Some examples:

- http://antoviaque.org/docs/tutorials/backbone-relational-tutorial/
- https://github.com/DzemalBecirevic/Ria

Answer (score 1):

[Recipes with Backbone](http://recipeswithbackbone.com/), it costs **$24** but it worths it.